# Does gcc optimize successive additions?

Tags: gcc, optimization, addition

I was wondering, does gcc optimizes this (consider `a` as an integer which value is unknown to gcc) :

```
foo(a + 2 + 3);
```

To this :

```
foo(a + 5);
```

Or does it translates it to two additions ? Do I have to add a specific optimization level ?

Thanks !

Comment: Use the `-S` option to see what assembly GCC compiles to.

Comment: It's called "constant folding".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. It does so even without optimization enabled.

It has to because for instance:

```
int x[2+2];
```

is legal C, even though the size must be known at compile time.

Comment: Very nice answer and example!